# SPF record (DNS)

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

Please help to set up a SPF record. I have found several SPF record generators but all questions are too complicated and I am afraid to make something wrong.

I want to allow sending mail only from:

1) from all IP addresses that are listed as A records for this domain.
2) from other servers in my data center in the same IP range
2) from Gmail servers - my domain is set up to use Gmail (all MX records are Google's MX records). Google's instructions say to include **include:_spf.google.com ~all** in the SPF record. Do I need **mx** in this case?

Which is correct:

**v=spf1 a ip4:111.222.333.0/24 include:_spf.google.com ~all**

or

**v=spf1 mx a ip4:111.222.333.0/24 include:_spf.google.com ~all**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first is correct for testing. The second is unnecessary because of the Google include.

When you're done testing (send an e-mail from all authorized servers to a test service) change the "~all" to "-all". The tilde indicates that you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

To add some details to Chris S's perfectly correct answer,

`v=spf1 a ip4:111.222.333.0/24 include:_spf.google.com -all` is correct.
You do not need to include `mx`, because you already have `include:_spf.google.com`, which allows gmail;
Since you said you want to allow sending mail only from these servers, should put a `-all` instead of `~all` to strictly enforce SPF rules. With a `~all`, other servers still be able to send email using your domain. 

**Note:** With a `-all`, users under your domain will not be able to send e-mails using alternative SMTP servers, such as yahoo, hotmail, etc.

Depends on configuration of your e-mail servers software, you may need also put your ip6 address in SPF. When both ip4 and ip6 is enabled on your side, some email server softwares(e.g. sendmail) will use ip6 to delivery to gmail addresses, and lack of ip6 SPF record will cause gmail servers to refuse e-mails from your server.